# R: Spread key-value pairs when keys are in different columns and return value frequency

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have searched around but could not find a particular answer to my question.

**Suppose I have a data frame df:**

```
df = data.frame(id = c(10, 11, 12, 13, 14),
                V1 = c('blue', 'blue', 'blue', NA, NA),
                V2 = c('blue', 'yellow', NA, 'yellow', 'green'),
                V3 = c('yellow', NA, NA, NA, 'blue'))
```

I want to use the values of V1-V3 as unique column headers and I want the occurrence frequency of each of those per row to populate the rows.

**Desired output:**

```
desired = data.frame(id = c(10, 11, 12, 13, 14),
                     blue = c(2, 1, 1, 0, 1),
                     yellow = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0),
                     green = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1))
```

There is probably a really cool way to do this with tidyr::spread and dplyr::summarise. However, I don't know how to spread the V* columns when the keys I want to spread by are all over the place in different columns and include NAs.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `melt`and `dcast` from package `reshape2`:

```
dcast(melt(df, id="id", na.rm = TRUE), id~value)

  id blue green yellow
1 10    2     0      1
2 11    1     0      1
3 12    1     0      0
4 13    0     0      1
5 14    1     1      0
```

As suggested by [David Arenburg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001626/david-arenburg), it is just simpler to use `recast`, a wrapper for `melt` and `dcast`:

```
recast(df, id ~ value, id.var = "id")[,1:4]   # na.rm is not possible then

  id blue green yellow
1 10    2     0      1
2 11    1     0      1
3 12    1     0      0
4 13    0     0      1
5 14    1     1      0
```

Comment: Also `recast(df, id ~ value, id.var = "id")` from the same package

Comment: Thanks @DavidArenburg, I didn't know abour `recast`

Comment: Thank you Hubert -- that was exactly what I needed. Wasn't aware that we can use formulas inside _melt_