# Spreading key value pairs into columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr, dcast

I'm stuck with the following data wrangling problem. Each dataset has multiple values of `aValue` per one value of `aName`. This can be easily represented in a tidy data frame.

```
someDatasets <- list(dataset1 = data.frame(aName = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b"), aValue = 1:5, dataset = "ds1"),
                     dataset2 = data.frame(aName = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "c", "c"), aValue = (1:6)*10 , dataset = "ds2"),
                     dataset3 = data.frame(aName = c("a", "c", "c", "c"), aValue = (1:4)*100, dataset = "ds3"))

tidyData <- Reduce(dplyr::bind_rows, someDatasets)
```

I would like to "spread" the dataset variable into individual columns. (I was not able to use `tidyr::spread` to create desired output because of duplicate keys.)

```
###
# Desired output
###
# aName ds1 ds2 ds3
# a     1   10  100
# a     2   20  NA
# a     3   30  NA
# b     4   40  NA
# b     5   NA  NA
# c     NA  50  200
# c     NA  60  300
# c     NA  NA  400
```

Is there a tidy way to generate desired output ?

ps: I'm aware of [spread-key-value-pairs-when-keys-are-in-different-columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39882107/r-spread-key-value-pairs-when-keys-are-in-different-columns-and-return-value-fr) question but the solution

```
dcast(melt(someDatasets, id = "aName", na.rm = TRUE), aName~value)
```

does not produce the desired output because an aggregate function `length` is used.

Comment: Where is length used and why is that not desirable?

Comment: Maybe `bind_rows(someDatasets) %>% group_by(dataset) %>% mutate(aName = paste0(aName, 1:n())) %>% spread(dataset, aValue) %>% mutate(aName = substr(aName, 1, 1))`.

Comment: Add a secondary ID based on the grouping of "aName" and "dataset" (from your "tidyData" dataset) and then use `dcast`. For instance, if you had named the secondary ID as "ID", you can do `dcast(tidyDataWithID,  aName + ID ~ dataset, value.var = "aValue")`.

Comment: @Hack-R `dcast` says "Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length". @lukeA very close yes, except that it results in 5 "c" rows where 3 rows would actually suffice. @a Hancard And Mohair Thank you, that worked `tidyData %>%
  group_by(aName, dataset) %>%
  mutate(ID = 1:n()) %>%
  dcast(aName + ID ~ dataset, value.var = "aValue")`. If you post an answer with explanation I could accept it as an answer.

Comment: As I see it, there must be more information. Something which can be used as ID. For example row 1 and 2 of dataset 1 cannot be distinguished: they both have aName = a and dataset = ds1.

Comment: @Drey see my updated answer, where the same result is achieved by using `dplyr` and `tidyr`, including just 3 rows for `c` instead of 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in comments by @lukeA and @A Handcart and Mohair, you can add an additional ID to your data to avoid the **duplicate keys** problem.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

tidyData = bind_rows(someDatasets) %>% 
   group_by(dataset, aName) %>% 
   mutate(id = paste0(aName, 1:n())) %>% 
   ungroup() %>% 
   select(-aName)

# head(tidyData)
# Source: local data frame [6 x 3]
# 
#   aValue dataset    id
#    <dbl>   <chr> <chr>
# 1      1     ds1    a1
# 2      2     ds1    a2
# 3      3     ds1    a3
# 4      4     ds1    b1
# 5      5     ds1    b2
# 6     10     ds2    a1
```

`id` is now unique within each group (dataset) so we can proceed with spreading:

```
tidyData %>% 
   spread(dataset, aValue) %>% 
   mutate(id = substr(id, 1, 1))

# Source: local data frame [10 x 4]
# 
#      id   ds1   ds2   ds3
#   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     a     1    10   100
# 2     a     2    20    NA
# 3     a     3    30    NA
# 4     b     4    40    NA
# 5     b     5    NA    NA
# 6     c    NA    50   200
# 7     c    NA    60   300
# 8     c    NA    NA   400
```

Comment: Thank you. The second output is based on non-unique `aValue`s and `tidyData %>%
  group_by(aName, dataset) %>%
  mutate(ID = 1:n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  tidyr::unite(col = "aName", aName, ID, sep = "#") %>%
  tidyr::spread(dataset, aValue) %>%
  tidyr::separate(col = "aName", into = c("aName", "ID"), remove = T, sep = "#") %>%
  dplyr::select(- ID)` did the job. I feel like the `tidyr` version is more verbose than the `reshape2` one - that is unfortunate.

Comment: @Drey Sorry, I forgot to update the upper part of the code - see now (slightly less verbose...)

Comment: retouring `unite` and `separate` makes indeed more readble. Thank you and others again.